# Do nvidia drivers need reinstalling after changing memory slots on Linux (UEFI)?

Tags: linux, drivers, uefi, nvidia

I've changed the memory slots (took out a set of 3x32Gb and put a fresh set of 3x32Gb of ECC type) on a Linux computer with Ubuntu 22.04 and upon reboot, the `nvidia-smi` command complained that the drivers weren't up to date or properly installed or found on the system.

The only reason I can think of for this happening is some sort of UEFI signature needed after some hardware components on the system being changed.

Do nvidia drivers need reinstalling after changing memory slots on Linux? Is this related to the way UEFI works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do nvidia drivers need reinstalling after changing memory slots on
> Linux (UEFI)?

No

Also when you say you've moved memory slots - do you mean actual memory slots or do you mean PCIe slots - if the former then there's usually a 'fill order' for your memory, you should stick to that as doing anything else just slows down your machine, the server lid often has it printed on the inside. If you meant the latter then again, no, it'll make no difference.

Comment: Took out a set of 3x32Gb and put a fresh set of 3x32Gb of ECC type. So it's new hardware components, but I am surprised it's affected the Nvidia Drivers.

Comment: I'm sure it didn't, honestly I think it's just a coincidence - the post-boot environment doesn't care about things like ECC.